# python function definition to find if all values in a list are even odd or neither

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return-value, definition

I am struggling in a college beginner's computer science course and just need simple homework help.

Now, we are currently working on function definitions, and I have to write a program that reads a list of integers, and outputs whether the list contains all even numbers, odd numbers, or neither. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers in the list. The first integer is not in the list (it just tells the length of the list).

My program must define and call the following two functions. `def is_list_even()` returns true if all integers in the list are even and false otherwise. `def is_list_odd()` returns true if all integers in the list are odd and false otherwise. If the list is all even I also have to print 'all even'. If the list is odd, I must print 'all odd'. If the list has both, I must print 'not even or odd'.

I have been able to get all of the integers I need into the list, however the definitions are what I am struggling with (formatting, returning it, etc.). I have pasted the code I have so far below (this website has changed the format of it) but my program produces no output. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
n = int(input())

my_list =[]

for i in range(n):

    num = int(input())

    my_list.append(num)

def IsListEven(my_list):

    for i in range(len(my_list)):

        if my_list[i] % 2 == 0:

            return True

        else:

            return False

def IsListOdd(my_list):

    for i in range(len(my_list)):

        if my_list[i] % 2 == 1:

            return True

        else:

            return False

def GetUserValues():

    if IsListOdd(my_list) == True:

        print("all odd")

    elif IsListEven(my_list) == True:

        print("all Even")

    else:

        print("not even or odd")
```

Comment: `return` *immediately* ends a function. You have `return` inside your `for` loops which guarantees they will never loop over all the values. For example `IsListEven` begins promisingly, but then on the first iteration of the for loop returns either True or False regardless of home many items you intended to look at.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code in particular?

Comment: can use `all` built in to function to check if all numbers are `even` or `odd`. For example, determing if a list contains only `odd` numbers, can do: `all(map(lambda x: x%2, my_list))`

Comment: I need the program to produce an output 'all even', 'all odd' or, 'not even or odd'. When I run it no output is produced though. It is not showing me any errors. I am going to try to move around the return statements, but am a bit confused on how to do that. (I apologize, my computer science teacher has not been great at explaining things to the class.)

Comment: Do you have a debugger?  This is an easy problem when you see what your code is actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` will immediately break the loop, so use a holding boolean variable like:

```
def IsListEven(my_list):

    allEven = True

    for i in range(len(my_list)):

        if my_list[i] % 2 != 0:

            allEven = False
     
    return allEven

def IsListOdd(my_list):
    
    allOdd = True

    for i in range(len(my_list)):

        if my_list[i] % 2 != 1:

            allOdd = False

    return allOdd

def GetUserValues():

    if IsListOdd(my_list) == True:

        print("all odd")

    elif IsListEven(my_list) == True:

        print("all Even")
```

But your functions can be one liner if you use `all()`, an example to check if all is odd

```
my_list = [1,3,5]
print(all(x % 2 == 1 for x in my_list))
```

Comment: The final one-liner could be simplified to `print(all(x % 2 == 1 for x in my_list))`

Answer (score 2):

Use a flag to check if all the values satisfy the condition.
Example :

```
def IsListEven(my_list):

    answer = True

    for i in range(len(my_list)):

        if my_list[i] % 2 == 0: # As pointed in comment, use != for isEven

            answer = False
            break

    return answer
```

Comment: That's unnecessary. You can just do`return False` in the loop and `return True` at the end.

Comment: @Brian no, here it has to return the boolean flag, but best is to use `all()`

Comment: The logic here is incorrect, it should be `if my_list[i] % 2 != 0`

Comment: @WasifHasan There's no need for a flag. See the accepted answer.

Comment: @Brian the accepted answer is mine!

Comment: @Wasif I think bbnumber2 had the accepted answer when I posted that.

Answer (score 1):

There is one major logical error, and a few minor syntactical fixes.

Currently, the `IsListEven()` and `IsListOdd()` functions will immediately return when they find an even or odd element, respectively. This leads to lists being marked as "even" even if only the very first element is even (and vice versa). One way this can be solved is by returning false when the opposite is found, and true if not:

```
def IsListEven(my_list):
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] % 2 == 1:
            return False
    return True
```

and

```
def IsListOdd(my_list):
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] % 2 == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

More explicitly, this can be defined with a [`for-else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement (although not completely necessary here):

```
def IsListEven(my_list):
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] % 2 == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

In terms of syntax, there isn't much of a reason to use list indexing within the for loops. A simpler method is to access the numbers directly:

```
def IsListEven(my_list):
    for i in my_list:
        if i % 2 == 1:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

Additionally, the final checks can be simplified because the returned values are booleans:

```
if IsListOdd(my_list):
    print("all odd")
elif IsListEven(my_list):
    print("all Even")
else:
    print("not even or odd")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track you just need to simplify the logic in your for loops a little:

```
def get_int_input(prompt: str) -> int:
    num = -1
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Enter an integer, try again...")
    return num

def is_list_even(lst: list[int]) -> bool:
    for x in lst:
        if x % 2 != 0:
            return False
    return True

def is_list_odd(lst: list[int]) -> bool:
    for x in lst:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    num_elements = get_int_input("Enter the number of elements: ")

    my_list = []
    for i in range(num_elements):
        my_list.append(get_int_input(f"Enter element {i + 1}: "))

    print(my_list)

    if is_list_even(my_list):
        print("all even")
    elif is_list_odd(my_list):
        print("all odd")
    else:
        print("mix of evens and odds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Enter the number of elements: 5
Enter element 1: 1
Enter element 2: 1
Enter element 3: 1
Enter element 4: 1
Enter element 5: 1
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
all odd
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Enter the number of elements: 3
Enter element 1: 2
Enter element 2: 2
Enter element 3: 2
[2, 2, 2]
all even
```

**Example Usage 3:**

```
Enter the number of elements: 4
Enter element 1: 1
Enter element 2: a
Error: Enter an integer, try again...
Enter element 2: 2
Enter element 3: 1
Enter element 4: 7
[1, 2, 1, 7]
mix of evens and odds
```